# Spiting first part and last part from string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am looking for separating string into first part and last part. Basically, last word is considered as last part and the remaning part is called first part. Below is what I have tried so far

```
    DECLARE @Col TABLE 
    (
     ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
    ) 

    INSERT INTO @Col(ColumnName)
    VALUES
    ('ABC, DEF GHI,'), -- Expeted output: FirstPart: ABC, DEF  LastPart: GHI
    ('A,'), -- Expected Output: FirstPart: NULL LastPart: A
    (' '), -- Expected Output: FirstPart: NULL LastPart: NULL
    (''), -- Expected Output: FirstPart: NULL LastPart: NULL
    ('A , '),-- Expected Output: FirstPart: NULL LastPart: A
    ('ABC DEF G.HI, ') -- Expected Output: FirstPart: ABC DEF LastPart: G.HI

    SELECT '' AS FirstPart, -- I don't know how to get the FirstPart of the string 
SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 1, LEN(ColumnName) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(ColumnName))) AS LastPart FROM @Col
```

Comment: I'm not getting the logic here. care to elaborate?

Comment: @ZoharPeled For a given string, I want to have last word (will be called LastPart) and the renaming part of the string will become FirstPart. String will be divided into two parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it - using a couple of common table expressions and relying on the fact that trailing spaces are ignored in string comparison I came up with this (I know it looks cumbersome and perhaps it's the time (it's almost 1 A.M here), but it gives the correct results):

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  ColumnName, 
            CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(ColumnName), PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', REVERSE(ColumnName))) As LastSpaceBeforeLastWord
    FROM @Col
), CTELastPart AS
(
    SELECT  ColumnName,
            LastSpaceBeforeLastWord,
            TRIM(
                CASE 
                    -- LEN('   ') also returns 0...
                    WHEN LEN(ColumnName) = 0 THEN NULL
                    WHEN LastSpaceBeforeLastWord = 0 THEN ColumnName
                    ELSE RIGHT(ColumnName, LastSpaceBeforeLastWord)
                END
            ) As LastPart
    FROM CTE1
)
                   -- '    ' equals ''...
SELECT ColumnName, TRIM(NULLIF(REPLACE(ColumnName, LastPart, ''), '')) As FirstPart, LastPart
FROM CteLastPart
```

Results:

```
ColumnName      FirstPart   LastPart
ABC, DEF GHI,   ABC, DEF    GHI,
A,              NULL        A,
                NULL        NULL
                NULL        NULL
A ,             NULL        A ,
ABC DEF G.HI,   ABC DEF     G.HI,
```

Online demo on [<kbd>DB<>Fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ffe506035e2d377820bce6532d403fe6)

Comment: +1 for the excellent solution (as usual) and beating me by a minute. Note, however, no commas should be returned and TRIM is available only on 2017.

Comment: Good points. Commas can be easily removed as you've shown in your answer. As I wrote, it's getting late here so I'll probably leave that change for tomorrow. BTW, 7 minutes but who's counting? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
SELECT 
  c.ColumnName,
  FirstPart = SUBSTRING(clean.string,0,NULLIF(f.X,1)),
  LastPart = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(clean.string, f.X, 8000))
FROM @Col AS c
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(c.ColumnName,',',''))) AS clean(string)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
  NULLIF(LEN(clean.string),0)+SIGN(LEN(clean.string)-1)-
    CHARINDEX(' ',RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(clean.string)))))) AS f(X);
```

**Returns:**

```
ColumnName           FirstPart   LastPart
-------------------- ----------- ----------
ABC, DEF GHI,        ABC DEF     GHI
A,                   NULL        A
                     NULL        NULL
                     NULL        NULL
A ,                  NULL        A  
ABC DEF G.HI,        ABC DEF     G.HI
```

Comment: change `'A , '` to `'A . '` (the comma to a dot) and it will return `.` as last part in that row. That's why I've used `patindex(%[a-z]%...` in my code - Though I do admit that using cross apply vs common table expressions do lead to a shorter, more readable code.

Comment: Ha! Our comments crossed paths... I *think*, based on the OP's "Expected Results" comments that 'A . ' should return `A` as FirstPart and a `.` as LastPart.  Yes - I have been liking cross apply a lot lately for cleaning up my code.

Comment: That's for the OP to know, we can only guess, at least for now :-). +1 for seeing things I've missed (And for the usage of cross apply instead of a cte)